# javascript regular expression error in test function?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
s = /^([a-z\d\.-_]+)@([a-z\d-]+)\.([a-z]{2,8})(\.[a-z]{2,8})?$/g
s.test("a@gmail.com")
true
s.test("a@gmail.com")
false
s.test("a@gmail.com")
true
```

I am not able to understand the behaviour of the program it generate true and false in cyclic order but if i remove g  for the last of the regular expression then it behaves normally

Comment: You've found the answer. Use `/g` when you need it and not when you don't.

Comment: This is an issue with `test()`. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag)